# connect via ssh to jhipster docker container on CentOS 7

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, docker, jhipster

I have installed docker (`version 0.11.1-dev, build 02d20af/0.11.1`); seems to the latest available in any case for CentOS 7 (`yum update docker` says there are no updates).

As per [installation instructions on jhipster site](http://jhipster.github.io/installation.html) I've pulled the current image and run:

```
sudo docker run -v ~/jhipster:/jhipster -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 4022:22 -t --name jhipster jdubois/jhipster-docker
```

The image is running OK. However I fail to connect via *ssh*. If I run *ssh* with verbose option:

```
ssh -vv -p 4022 jhipster@localhost
```

I get:

```
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 4022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/normunds/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by ::1
```

In case I try to reach another Ubuntu host I receive the same sequence (apart from host, port and OpenSSH version), but instead of the last line with "Connection closed" it has:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
```

and eventually it connects successfully.

I have tried to connect to via *localhost:4022*, *ip-of-container:22*; from local or remote hosts with the same results.

So the problems seems to be in container or docker (or eventually ubuntu settings within docker). However `docker top jhipster` shows me *sshd* is running and - yes, the trace evidently shows that I reach the *ssh* server.

Any ideas?

**Edited** I ran docker image, so that it enters command line, then ran *sshd* in debug mode:

> sudo docker run -v ~/projects:/jhipster -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 4022:22 -t -i --name jhipster jdubois/jhipster-docker /bin/bash
>
> /usr/sbin/sshd -d

in order to debug further. On connection attempt *sshd* fails with:

> chroot("/var/run/sshd"): Operation not permitted [preauth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) *ssh* access

**CentOS 7**
It looks that the problem is that *CentOS 7* repository has only an old Docker version; both *CentOS 6* and *Ubuntu* use version 1.1.2. The issue on *CentOS 7* can be bypassed by running the image with command line option (as in edited section of OP) then running:

> sed 's/UsePrivilegeSeparation yes/UsePrivilegeSeparation no/' -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>
> /usr/sbin/sshd

**CentOS 6**
When testing in *CentOS 6* running *Docker* 1.1.2, I did not have the same problem (*ssh* connection got further, hence I assume the error on *CentOS 7* was caused by the *Docker* version), however *ssh* disconnected as soon as connected with an error on client side *pam session not opened* and on container side *PAM: pam_open_session(): Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session*.

Here it looks it is related to  [[FIXED] ubuntu 14.04 container with ssh login issues #5663](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5663) . Even if it is marked as "fixed". In any case one of the solutions mentioned in the thread that I tried was enough to fix my *ssh* connectivity issue:

> sed '/pam_loginuid.so/s/^/#/g' -i /etc/pam.d/*

It seems, it would also be enough to run:

> sed 's/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/' -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config

instead, but I did not try this option.

**Conclusion**: *ssh* connectivity on CentOS can be fixed by running the image with a command line

> sudo docker run -v ~/projects:/jhipster -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 4022:22 -t -i --name jhipster jdubois/jhipster-docker /bin/bash

then different "fixes" for CentOS 6/CentOS 7 as discussed above, then

> /usr/sbin/sshd

2) At this point we might ask: "why *ssh* at all"? Once we arrive on command line all we need to do is:

```
su jhipster
cd /jhipster
yo jhipster
```

right? Nearly so, but here we have another problem. Again different on both *CentOS* versions. And it is present also if we connect via *ssh*.

On **CentOS 7** that is using the old *Docker* version we need to modify *selinux* context of host directory (in our case ~/jhipster):

> chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t ~/jhipster

On **CentOS 6** this is not necessary (and *svirt_sandbox_file_t* does not exist as an option), however the shared folder inside the container is unavailable for the user *jhipster*. We first, as the *root*, need to run:

> chown jhipster:jhipster /jhipster

And then already:

```
su jhipster
cd /jhipster
yo jhipster
```

Comment: What do you mean by "old Docker version" ?

Comment: at that point Centos 7 repositories contained only a relatively old version. Today it seems to be pretty uptodate.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but it still needs `svirt_sandbox_file_t`, this is not related to old docker version, but to enhanced security in Centos7.