# Docker hangs when starting jdubois/jhipster container in OS X

Tags: osx-mavericks, docker, jhipster

I'm trying to run a jhipster app on Docker on OS X 10.9.4.

I installed boot2docker and was able to get the hello-world container to run.

I followed the instructions on the jhipster site, pulling the jdubois/jhipster-docker image and creating a ~/jhipster directory.

I set up my /etc/sudoers file so that my DOCKER_HOST environment variable would propagate. I then tried to run the docker image:

```
sudo docker run -v ~/jhipster:/jhipster -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 35729:35729 -p 4022:22 -t jdubois/jhipster-docker
```

This just hangs forever. I tried to SSH to the container from another terminal window, but it just says connection refused.

Any idea what I should check next?

Answer (score 1):

Well *jhipster* docker image is not really nicely done in a sense that it runs in the current terminal window, but not as a daemon or at least not entering command line.

As for SSH, on OS X there might be the same issues that I encountered when connecting from CentOS: [connect via ssh to jhipster docker container on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428669/connect-via-ssh-to-jhipster-docker-container-on-centos-7)

I assume you could try my analyses and suggestions for Cent OS 6 (see the answer below) **Edited:** basically just forget about SSH and run container to enter directly in command line.